# cancan ability with specific actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to enable designer2 to only add/create battery. I am not sure what I am missing. The admin will be able to manage all, designer will be able to manage battery but has not access to roles and users. Designer2 will only create new but cannot delete or edit and has not access to user/role.

code in the ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin

      can :manage, :all


    elsif user.has_role? :designer1
      can :manage, :Battery


    elsif user.has_role? :designer2
      can [:read,:add], Battery

    end

    else
      can :read, :all 
    end 
end
```

Views/batteries/index.html.slim

```
- model_class = Battery
form.navbar-search.pull-right
  form.input-append method="get"
    div.input-append
      input.form-control placeholder="Search" type="text" name="keyword" value="#{params[:keyword]}"
      - if params[:keyword]
        = link_to batteries_path, class: 'btn' do
          i.icon-remove
      button.btn type="submit"
        i.icon-search

div class="page-header"
  h1=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize.titleize
table class="table table-striped"
  thead
    tr

      th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name)
      th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:battery_type)
      th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:manufacturer)
      th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:model)
      th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:volt)
      th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:capacity)
      th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:comments)

      / th= model_class.human_attribute_name(:created_at)
      - if can? :manage, Battery
        th=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions")
  tbody
    - @batteries.each do |battery|
      tr

        td= battery.name
        td= battery.battery_type
        td= battery.manufacturer
        td= battery.model
        td= battery.volt.volt
        td= battery.capacity.capacity
        td= battery.comments
        / td=l battery.created_at
        - if can? :manage, Battery
          td
            = link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")), edit_battery_path(battery), :class => 'btn btn-mini'
            '
            = link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")), battery_path(battery), :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) }, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger'

- if can? :manage, Battery
  = link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")), new_battery_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary'

= paginate @batteries, :theme => 'twitter-bootstrap'
br
```

Comment: Could explain a little better the results you're having and compare them to the results you expected?
I think there is an error in the last `else` section at the end of your controller. Try removing the `else` and the `end` leaving only the `can :read, :all` code.

Comment: Also, in your view, you would usually verify if user can do a specif action. So instead of `if can? :manage, Battery` before the link to edit, you should specify the action like `if can? :edit, Battery`. If a user can :manage, it means he can perform any action, including :edit.

Comment: With some help from a friend, I figured it out. Here is how:in ability,       can :create, Battery   in index i used the same - if can? :create, Battery